# Too much delay playing a sound after pressing button

Tags: android, audio

I'm creating a sampler app for school. I've wrote code which plays a sample when I press and hold a button and stops when I release it. My problem is that it has too much latency. It takes too long after I press the button to play the sound.

My audio files are mp3's.

Here's my code:

```
smpl1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
{   
  public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent theMotion)
  {
    switch (theMotion.getAction())
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        sample = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bassdrum);
        smpl1.setText("ON");
        smpl1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        sample.start();
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        smpl1.setText("OFF");
        smpl1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        sample.stop();
        break;
    }
    return true;        
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the `sample` object before the button press, then just use the start / stop functionality in your handler code.

Comment: you may need to `prepare` it, too